# iam getting this error 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.xx.xx.192" while applying migrations in .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

I'm Getting This Error While Applying Migrations To Create New Database Hosted in database Cluster in Digitalocean.

my connection string is:

```
                var conn = "User ID=test;Password=testPassword;Server=db-postgresql-tor1-xxxxx-do-user-xxxxxxxxx-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com;port=25060;Database=TestAuthentication;Integrated Security=false;Pooling=true;";
```

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.xx.xx.192", user "test", database "TestAuthentication", SSL off
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 933
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 973
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.Auth.cs:line 22
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 389
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 240
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 119
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception data:
Severity: FATAL
SqlState: 28000
MessageText: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.xx.xx.192", user "test", database "TestAuthentication", SSL off
File: auth.c
Line: 496
Routine: ClientAuthentication
28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.xx.xx.192", user "test", database "TestAuthentication", SSL off

Answer (score 0):

That's a PostgreSQL error. You are trying to access a database in another computer but the client is not authorised by the server. If you have access to the server, you can edit the pg_hba.conf file and add an entry to XXX.xx.xx.192. There are plenty of examples in the same file.

Comment: I don't have access to pg_hba.conf but I added my IP address in trusted sources in digitalocean and still having the same problem